# Edit html 5 video loaded with ajax with chrome extension

Tags: ajax, google-chrome

Using a chrome extension I want to change autoplay of a certain video on a specific webpage. I have the following manifest.json:

```
{
"manifest_version": 2,
"version": "1.0",

"content_scripts": [
{
"matches": ["http://example.com"],
"js": ["content.js"],
"run_at": "document_end"
}
]
}
```

In my content.js I have the following code:

```
myVid=document.getElementById("video");
myVid.autoplay=true;
```

This extension works fine if the webpage simply has a -tag from the beginning. However, the page I want to use this extension loads the -tag using ajax, which makes it more complicated.How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Run your code whenever the document changes.

There is an event called: 'DOMSubtreeModified'.